# Is there in PySpark a parameter equivalent to scikit-learn's sample_weight?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am currently using the `SGDClassifier` provided by the `scikit-learn` library. When I use the `fit` method I can set the `sample_weight` parameter:

> Weights applied to individual samples. If not provided, uniform
>   weights are assumed. These weights will be multiplied with
>   class_weight (passed through the constructor) if class_weight is
>   specified

I want to switch to PySpark and to use the `LogisticRegression` class. Anyway I cannot find a parameter similar to `sample_weight`. There is a `weightCol` parameter but I think it does something different.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I think [`weightCol`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.weightCol) does exactly that

Comment: I see, @desertnaut if you answer officially I'll accept your answer. I thought it was something different but it seems that you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a `weightCol` parameter but I think it does something different.

On the contrary, `weightCol` of Spark ML does exactly that; from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.weightCol) (emphasis added):

> `weightCol` = *Param(parent='undefined', name='weightCol', doc='weight column name. If this is not set or empty, we treat all **instance** weights as 1.0.')*