# Strategies to assign specific weights to training instances

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am working on a Machine Learning Classification Model in which the user can provide label instances that should help improve the model. 
More relevance needs to be given to the latest instances given by the user than for those instances that were previously available for training.

In particular, I am developing my machine learning models in python using Sklearn libraries.

So far I've only found the strategy of oversampling particular instances as a possible solution to the problem. With this strategy I would create multiple copies of the instances for which I want to give higher relevance.

Other strategy that I've found, but it seems not help under these conditions is:

- Strategies that focus on giving weights for each class. This strategy is highly used in multiple libraries like Sklearn by default. However, this generalizes the idea to a class level and doesn't help me to put focus on particular instances

I've look for multiple strategies that might help provide specific weights for individual instances but most have focused on class level instead of instance level weights.

I read some suggestions to multiple the loss function by some factors for instances in tensor flow models, but this seems to be mostly applicable to neural network models in Tensor flow.

I wonder if anyone has information of other approaches that might helps with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've look for multiple strategies that might help provide specific weights for individual instances but most have focused on class level instead of instance level weights.

This is not accurate; most scikit-learn classifiers provide a `sample_weight` argument in their `fit` methods, which does exactly that. For example, here is the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) reference for Logistic Regression:

> **sample_weight : *array-like, shape (n_samples,) optional***
>
> Array of weights that are assigned to individual samples. If not provided, then each sample is given unit weight.

Similar arguments exist for most scikit-learn classifiers, e.g. [decision trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit), [random forests](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit) etc, even for [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) (not a classifier). Be sure to check the [SVM: Weighted samples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html) example in the docs.

The situation is roughly similar for other frameworks; see for example own answer in [Is there in PySpark a parameter equivalent to scikit-learn's sample_weight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949825/is-there-in-pyspark-a-parameter-equivalent-to-scikit-learns-sample-weight/56952784#56952784)

What's more, scikit-learn also provides a utility function to compute `sample_weight` in cases of imbalanced datasets: [`sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight.html)